# Syntax error in SQL statement when I try to execute a TSQL script against an H2 dataBase on Java

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, h2

I try to execute a TSQL script from a Java program against a H2 in memory data base, but I can not get it to work.

I tried to use the right option to the DB url to specify it's in MS SQL server mode, don't work..

here's my code :

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
System.out.println("Driver O.K.");

Connection conn;
String url = "jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer";
String user = "sa";
String passwd = "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
System.out.println("Connexion effective !");

RunScript.execute(url, user, passwd, "DataBase1.sql", Charset.forName("UTF-8"), false);
```

I get this : "Syntax error in SQL statement "USE ""ERMS_CMDB""
GO[*] etc, etc...."

The SQL script is correct, it execute correctly MicroSoft SQL Server

Comment: oh.. thanks, didn't notice that all the features were support

Comment: If you want an answer to your question about a syntax error in your SQL, you should post your SQL. Also the full error message that you get.